# How to align text to center with custom font-family applied to Textbox in winRT XAML app

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I am working on winRT C# app. I have Textbox with custom font-family. Due to custom font-family my text in Textbox is aligned to top of Textbox. I tried to set VerticalContentAlignment to "center" but it still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so sure it's because of your font, and more likely expected behavior of the `TextBox`. I would take a look at the control template for your `TextBox` and check your `Setter`'s and `ContentPresenter` to see if there isn't a property set to make it that way. Otherwise I think you can touch it via something like;

```
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
         <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
      </Style>
  </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: got the help : "http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappsuidesign/thread/2ce5e846-40e5-4c2f-b061-ccf5b21d8fc5/?prof=required" i think same as Chris's answer.